# The number of partial derangements of a $52$-card deck (ignoring suits)

Tags: combinatorics, derangements

I was reading this paper by Ekhad, Koutschan, and Zeilberger titled ["There are EXACTLY 1493804444499093354916284290188948031229880469556
Ways to Derange a Standard Deck of Cards (ignoring suits) [and many other such useful facts]"](https://sites.math.rutgers.edu/%7Ezeilberg/mamarim/mamarimPDF/multider.pdf), where the authors calculated the number of derangements of a deck of $52$ cards, where cards of the same rank are considered identical. My question is about generalizing this result to partial derangements.

> **Question:** For each $k\in \{0,1,\dots,52\}$, what is the number of permutations of a deck of $52$ cards which have exactly $k$ fixed points, where cards of the same rank are considered identical?

Call this number $D_k$. Would using the Laguerre polynomials that the paper uses suffice to compute $D_k$?  I believe that $$D_0 = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x} (L_4(x))^{13} dx = 1493804444499093354916284290188948031229880469556$$ from the paper. For 1 fixed point, we could have $$D_1 = -13\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x} (L_4(x))^{12} L_3(x) dx$$ and for more fixed points, we could have something like $$D_k = (-1)^{52-k} \sum_{p\in \text{partitions}(k,4)} \frac{13!}{\left( 13-|p| \right)!} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x} \left( \prod_{p_i\in p}L_{(4-p_i)}(x) \right) L_4(x)^{13-|p|}  dx$$

where $\text{partitions}(n, k)$ is the set of partitions of $n$ with parts $\leq k$ and $|p|$ is the number of parts in a particular partition $p$.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: a) A factor $-1$ is missing in $D_1$. b) I think $D_k$ doesn't account for symmetry properly. It seems correct for $k=2$, but e.g. for $k=3$ the partition $2+1$ is undercounted because you only count the unordered pairs of ranks, but the ranks are different because one has $1$ fixed point and one has $2$, so there are twice as many partial derangements as you're counting.

Comment: (You can get properly sized parentheses (and other paired delimiters) that adapt to their content by preceding them with `\left` and `\right`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea does work – but you also need to account for the locations of fixed points within their home ranks. Here is a SymPy program to calculate the $D_k$:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from sympy import *
from sympy.utilities.iterables import partitions
from sympy.abc import x
s = 4
r = 13

def even_gillis(partition):
    partition[0] = r - sum(partition.values())
    m1 = factorial(r) / prod(factorial(c) for c in partition.values()) # distribution of fixed point counts
    m2 = prod(binomial(s,p)**c for (p,c) in partition.items()) # distribution of fixed points in "home" rank
    return abs(m1 * m2 * integrate(exp(-x) * prod(laguerre(s-p, x)**c for (p,c) in partition.items()), [x, 0, oo]))

def partial_derangements(f):
    return sum(map(even_gillis, partitions(f, m=r, k=s)))

res = {}
for f in range(s*r+1):
    pd = partial_derangements(f)
    print(f, pd)
    res[f] = pd
print(sum(res.values()))
```

And here are the results:
$$
\begin{array}{r|l}
k&D_k\\
\hline
0&1493804444499093354916284290188948031229880469556\\
1&6340385757557016669128420681559913588527453996864\\
2&13266567232207057196014773086716987647277293815856\\
3&18238668284676205177418898082466616089067625607616\\
4&18526769548311847223050211825372407524039077015557\\
5&14826224260233156028288754354346995034911746027008\\
6&9732708392068246090956225651522314943138294316704\\
7&5388382133535087467858278212335850455674549925120\\
8&2567258926131602469308920690973149684353615798276\\
9&1068839557015030994188955669673671973162569909952\\
10&393534296458352079879548193177365201106785737968\\
11&129371970433250016992346298354693416312270368064\\
12&38271861262950277022473531520430194406090429150\\
13&10254432892901004797163139073870817866169740416\\
14&2502028211163453511033632375709022781594997632\\
15&558489068026035105701769031504044064553874048\\
16&114492933061917767485607764612228911867407264\\
17&21629266186692633175386060136767163967218560\\
18&3776237464936831529921454444732822904439616\\
19&610822862705574444615834900761255140405632\\
20&91737539975720228203466396152069450492503\\
21&12816366440544896999386077594111721526784\\
22&1668274956079648413449611940576063055040\\
23&202607555532030287897710870057828970496\\
24&22984837821463304425124924502086877192\\
25&2438138734503872483064403804289088896\\
26&242029379436229196341907014157600736\\
27&22499164519129073264215408330416768\\
28&1959697454240653635204549865387284\\
29&159998642365496645012580155674368\\
30&12248351055202924758280988299392\\
31&879338509214420888551480829696\\
32&59209757027395856005889630580\\
33&3739338499202164436917045824\\
34&221481166178568820575299248\\
35&12301956968645810278717632\\
36&640693604925620624217411\\
37&31283060497329005414400\\
38&1431888035067524589984\\
39&61438162479298023168\\
40&2471333583132294452\\
41&93214815560857536\\
42&3298149470856240\\
43&109531765355584\\
44&3417031057518\\
45&100213356672\\
46&2770050816\\
47&71660160\\
48&1814904\\
49&36608\\
50&1248\\
51&0\\
52&1
\end{array}$$
$$\Sigma=92024242230271040357108320801872044844750000000000=\frac{52!}{4!^{13}}$$