# What is a formula for enumerate multiset partial derangements?

Tags: combinatorics

How can you calculate the number of partial derangements of a multiset? For example, if I have the multiset {green, blue, blue, green, green, green, red, blue, red} and I want to find all derangements where 4 elements have not moved (4 fixed points) and $9-4=5$ elements have moved, I listed all of them and found there were 264 total.
I found these links helpful:

- [The number of partial derangements of a $52$-card deck (ignoring suits)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4645664/the-number-of-partial-derangements-of-a-52-card-deck-ignoring-suits)
- [Derangements of multisets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/147657/derangements-of-multisets)
- [https://sites.math.rutgers.edu/~zeilberg/mamarim/mamarimPDF/multider.pdf](https://sites.math.rutgers.edu/%7Ezeilberg/mamarim/mamarimPDF/multider.pdf)
- [Partial Derangement formula for permutation with repeated elements](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3361766/partial-derangement-formula-for-permutation-with-repeated-elements)

How can I enumerate multiset partial derangements?

This would be a fully general form of partial derangements.

Comment: When you say "four fixed points", are you looking for all possible derangements where at least 4 are fixed? Or are the 4 fixed points set by the questioner?

Comment: Multisets doesn't care about order, hence the "set" part in the name, so $\{1,1,2,2\}$ is the same as $\{2,2,1,1\}$, son it makes no sense to talk about fixed points. You should consider tuples: $(1,1,2,2)\ne (2,2,1,1)$.

Comment: Order matters. Four points Don't move. Five points move.

Comment: Exactly four points don't move. If it was at least four points don't move then I have to do 0 points don't move one points don't move two points don't move 3 points don't move and four points don't move which is not what I'm focused on.